# Flutter, Firebase, Google AI APIs & the EU cookie directive

Tags: firebase, cookies, flutter-web, cookie-policy, google-ai-platform

I am working on a web site with a front-end implemented in Flutter and a back-end relying on Firebase authentication, Firestore and Google AI APIs.  Following the EU cookie directive I have to inform my potential users about the usage of cookies and possible ways to opt out.

I suppose that this is a very common problem.  I seem to be unable, however, to find good information about how to deal with it.  So here my questions:

- Is there some standard way to deal with this problem?
- Are there Flutter widgets or Flutter plugins to show and deal with cookie alerts?
- How can I find out about the cookies Flutter, Firebase, and the Google AI APIs are relying on?
- Is it possible - and to which degree - to use a website based on Flutter, Firebase, and the Google AI APIs for users who reject the usage of cookies?

Thanks for your help,
Dietrich